# SXA Toolbox does not appear

Tags: sxa

I tried creating a new tenant with a new site, only using the basic2 theme. The site has no components. This happens with all created tenants.

```
20352 09:26:49 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.ToolboxFeed.IsItemRendering(Item item)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.c__DisplayClass6_0`1.b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.ToolboxFeed.get_GetRenderings()
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.ToolboxFeed.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Did you have any errors while tenant or site creation process? Is the SXA properly installed? I'm asking because others face this issue when the SXA installation was corrupted or tenant and site templates were not created properly. Ensure that it is fine.

Comment: Is there a way to check regarding installation problems? I grabbed the package from this and installed it on a blank instance and there were not any problems, would installing the package multiple times create any issues?

Comment: If there were no issues during the installation then it should be fine. I just recall that some peoples have the same exception when some templates were missing. Just to ensure try to re-install the SXA package. Later you can try to create new tenant and site to ensure that it is a different problem.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski This did not work, I downloaded the package from online, verified every thing was compatible with the SPE and Sitecore Versions, and then installed it, after which I rebuilt the indexes. Same exact error.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest here is to contact Sitecore support. Unfortunately, I won't find time during this week to investigate this.